# About infinite strategy sets and $\epsilon$-equilibrium from Game Theory: Analysis of Confilct by Roger Myerson

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am studying infinite strategy sets using Myerson's Game Theory: Analysis of Conflict. On Page 143, he defines an $\epsilon$-equilibrium as follows:

> **Definition** For any nonnegative number $\epsilon$, an $\epsilon$-equilibrium of any strategic-form game is a combination of randomized strategies such that no player could expect to gain more than $\epsilon$ by switching to any of his feasible strategies, instead of following the randomized strategy specified for him. That is, $\sigma$ is an $\epsilon$-equilibrium of $\Gamma$ if and only if
> \begin{align*}
> u_i(\sigma_{-i},[c_i]) - u_i(\sigma) \leq \epsilon,\quad \forall i \in N,\quad \forall c_i \in C_i.\tag1
> \end{align*}

Then, he put:

> when $\epsilon=0$, an $\epsilon$-equilibrium is just a Nash equilibrium in the usual sense.

However, I am a bit confused about this expression (1), because of that "$[c_i]$" there. Expression (1) means that no player could expect to gain more than $\epsilon$ by switching to any of his ***pure*** strategies (not ***feasible*** strategies, because they might as well be mixed strategies $\tau_i$). So I feel that the definition should have been stated as:

> $\sigma$ is an $\epsilon$-equilibrium of $\Gamma$ if and only if
> \begin{align*}
> u_i(\sigma_{-i},\tau_i) - u_i(\sigma) \leq \epsilon,\quad \forall i \in N,\quad \forall \tau_i \in \Delta(C_i).\tag2
> \end{align*}

I would like to know if my thought is correct. Is this a mistake of the book, or is the amended definition and expression unnecessary? I would really appreciate it if someone could help me check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether one uses mixed or pure strategies in that place.
If a mixed strategy $\tau_i\in\Delta(C_i)$ leads to a payoff larger than $u_i(\sigma)+\epsilon$, it must put positive probabilities on the set of pure strategies $[c_i]$ such that $u_i(\sigma_{-i},[c_i])>u_i(\sigma)+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you so much! So does it mean that, for the same reason, the Nash equilibrium may as well be defined as follows: $\sigma$ is a Nash equilibrium of $\Gamma$ if and only if $u_i(\sigma) \geq u_i(\sigma_{-i},[c_i]),\quad \forall i \in N,\quad \forall c_i \in C_i$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $~$